# I'm unsure if this output means there is an error or if it is saying if you see this on the lines it's an error

Tags: drivers

```
aiii@purplemacheen:~$ dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-    pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  amdgpu-pro     17.10-401251 amd64        Meta package to install   amdgpu Pr
aiii@purplemacheen:~$
```

What I'm trying to do is to install the amdgpu-pro version 17.10 drivers on Ubuntu 16.4.2. All steps from the guide were successful. I just don't know if ok, that's it, all settled everything is fine or not. I don't have a configuration control panel or anything installed now, and I'm not familiar with driver setup in Linux. My skills are very basic. The output confuses me because it says metapackage to install (which I did install I believe), and all that status, reinstall....no idea what it means....a little help?

Comment: One comment to note is that Ubunutu forced me to disable secure boot in order to use a third party proprietary driver, which I said OK. It had me make a password, which I was to enter on reboot; however, when I restarted my machine I got a blue screen saying something about MOK key. I chose continue to boot. At first Ubuntu wouldn't let me boot in, then I disabled secure boot in BIOS and it permitted me to login as normal.

Comment: Generally installing the package (and then rebooting) should be all that you need to do.  There is no "control panel" or similar needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally installing the package (and then rebooting) should be all that you need to do.  There is no "control panel" or similar needed.

The following command may show some driver info to confirm the driver is working, though it's not clear to me how the output may differ between amdgpu and amdgpu-pro.  There might also be some info in /var/log/Xorg.0.log.  Unfortunately I couldn't find any firm info on confirming it is working but most likely it is.

```
glxinfo|grep OpenGL
```

Comment: Well I got a lot of OpenGL answers as AMD Radeon 17.10, so it looks like all is to the good. Thanks friend!